# Booting from a remote ISO file

Tags: linux, boot, virtual-machine, iso-image, remote

Is there any way to boot my computer (or even my VirtualBox system) from a Linux live ISO file over the internet?
For example, I want to boot my computer through my live favorite distros before downloading them into my computer. Is there any way?

I'm sure that this method is already being used for example:

Some VPS providers can mount their customer's CD-ROMs to any Linux ISO file which they want (without any downloading) and then their customers can boot from that ISO.

So, I just wanna know how can I mount any Linux ISO file on my CD-ROM which that ISO **is not downloaded** locally.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can restart my computer remotely over VPN.  I do not see how you will do what you are trying to do

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_booting - possibly?

Comment: It's clear,
How could you boot your computer (or your virtual guest system) to a Linux ISO file which is over the internet and still has not downloaded its ISO file yet?

Comment: How do you know that VPS services do that? What makes you think they don't download the ISO?